# MySQL trigger for insert with no primary key

Tags: mysql, triggers, insert

I am trying to create a trigger that creates a primary key if that field is not stated in the insert statement.
EG:

```
insert into mydb.mytable (nonprimarykeyfield) values ('test');
```

The trigger is

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` TRIGGER `mydb`.`mytable_BEFORE_INSERT` 
BEFORE INSERT ON `mytable` 
FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        if NEW.pk is null then 
            SET NEW.pk = UUID();
        end if;
        set new.created_at=now();
    END
```

The insert fails with

```
Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry '' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

but there is no row with null as primary key.

Comment: Do you have a good reason to use `UUID()` for a PK?

Comment: UUID - wanted unique identifier that is secure

Comment: *"UUID - wanted unique identifier that is secure"*-> `PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT` is the only unique guaranteed identifier in MySQL.. `UUID()` can still duplicate with a very very small chance.. Besides when using `UUID()` as PK you "unalign" your Btree structure more as `UUID()` is more random meaning less faster selects vs `PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT` .. Also as InnoDB stores a copy of the primary key in de secondary indexes your secondary indexes will be become much larger vs `PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT`  ...

Comment: @Raymond Nijland - that is valuable advise

Comment: *"UUID - wanted unique identifier that is secure"* if you don't want to expose a `PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT` to the outside world which can be very understandable as others might know the number of your customers/orders you make in say a year to give a valid example.. You can choose to add a indexed `UUID()` column (maybe generated as a [Generated Column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html)) to select.. :Also make sure to also have a `PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT` besides that as that is very important in the InnoDB engine..

Answer (score 1):

Oviously, `NEW.pk` is not null, hence it's not getting the result of `UUID`. If you run the `insert` as you described, without specifyng the value of `pk`, then it has a `default` which causes duplication problems. Run

```
show create table mytable;
```

for more information.

EDIT:

Also, instead of triggers, you could just use auto_increment.

Comment: I had hoped that if the default value (NULL) was used then this would be picked up be the if block

Comment: @Datadimension can you edit your question and add the result of show create table mytable? It would be very informative.

Answer (score 0):

I realised that as the primary key is varchar it cannot obviously be null (tho confusingly MySQL Workbench allows this to be set in 'alter table', which immediately reverts back to ''. This was the cause of the problem.
Therefore the check should be made for '' at the 'if' block.
I have changed the trigger as below and insert works as expected

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` TRIGGER `mydb`.`mytable_BEFORE_INSERT` BEFORE INSERT ON `mytable` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    if NEW.pk ='' then 
        SET NEW.pk = UUID();
    end if;
    set new.created_at=now();
END
```

ADDITIONAL COMMENT:
As a discussion point, comments above from Raymond Nijland should be read in regard to database performance and design. Good stuff.